# Subtracting timestamp from json file in python

Tags: python, json

I've been trying to subtract two timestamps from two json files using python. The two json files were .srt files which have start and end time of the sentence. I converted srt into json to fetch the timestamp and subtract two different timestamps of the same sentence from two different files. I was using nested for loop to traverse along with subtracting the timestamps. It is not giving the desired result. Any other idea for subtracting two timestamps from different json files?

My code:

```
import json
from datetime import datetime

with open('SRT_en.json') as f:
   config_en= json.load(f)

with open('SRT_zh.json', encoding= "utf-8") as g:
   config_zh= json.load(g)

for time_en in config_en['captions']:
   b1=time_en['endTime']

   for time_zh in config_zh['captions']:
      b2= time_zh['endTime']
      c=b1.replace(',','.')
      
   d= b2.replace(',','.')
   d1= datetime.strptime(c,"%H:%M:%S.%f")
   d2= datetime.strptime(d,"%H:%M:%S.%f")
   print(d1-d2)
```

I might be sounding a total newbie over here, but really stuck over here.

Comment: Can you give an example of the data that you are running this code against?

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you're trying to do here. Also I think your indentation is off, I think `c=b1.replace(',','.')` should be an indent to the left. Can you provide the json files you're using? Are you trying to subtract two timestamps once, or iterate through multiple timestamps and subtract all of them?

Comment: @LayneBernardo Bernardo Thanks for the advice. I am trying to subtract timestamps of the same sentence and same line but they are the converted json files of .srt files. They are closed captions of two different languages, one english and one mandarin chinese. Sorry, but I can't share the files over here. It would be great if you guys could help me. I can explain you again if you still haven't got what I have said.

Comment: Sorry @JackTaylor but I have been forbid from sharing that file.

Comment: The code you have now iterates over the captions object and sets b1 and b2 to the `endTime` value each time. You don't do the actual subtraction until both iterations finish, so you're only going to get the difference between the last two timestamps in the objects. Also, with your current indentation, the second loop is nested. Indentation is important in Python. You should be getting both timestamps and subtracting them in each step of the iteration, not iterating over both separately and then subtracting the last values.

Comment: @LayneBernardo so how to iterate and subtract for every line's timestamp? That's what the main problem is. I am unable to think of anything rather than current code I have written above. I want to subtract timestamps of the same sentence, same line. For example:- if there are 20 lines in both the json files( by line I meant sentence line). Each line have its own start and end time. I want the time difference of the endTime of the first json file from the endTime of the second json file. And the difference should be of the same line or sentence. Do you have any solution for this?